# Listen to new comments in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I'm using the eSign REST API
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/

I am using embedded signing and get notifications for all the events using Connect (DS webhook)

I could not find a way to listen to comments events. Like adding a new comment or read the person I should notify has a comment.

Any options to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using DocuSign connect. You can retrieve all the comments using the eSign REST API, but they do not trigger webhooks at this time.

To get all comments use the [Comments:Get endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/comments/get/) of the v2.1 eSign API

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/comments/transcript
```

Comment: Thanks Inbar

Do you know what route I can use to retrieve the comments?
I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: Another question, I check this return a PDF file as a byte stream.

Is not possible to get a JSON response to read the comments?

Comment: No that I'm aware of, this is the only way I know to get the comments.